# PHP 8: Change upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, apache

I need to increase the values of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` from the default 2M to 10M.

(I need to do this for a specific vhost. Changing the values globally (for all vhosts) in php.ini is not an option.)

When running PHP 7, I did it by having the following in the Apache2 configuration file for the VirtualHost.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

After upgrading to PHP 8, these lines no longer work.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and have installed PHP 8 using the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Here is how I installed PHP:

```
sudo apt install php
sudo apt install php-fpm
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-fcgid
sudo a2enmod actions fcgid alias proxy_fcgi
```

Checking status:

```
sudo systemctl status php8.1-fpm
 php8.1-fpm.service - The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.1-fpm.service; enabled;  
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-08-28 15:32:37 UTC; 1min 30s ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm8.1(8)
   Main PID: 739 (php-fpm8.1)
[…]
```

Here is how part of the configuration file looks:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
[…]
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
<FilesMatch \.php$>:
    SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
[…]
</VirtualHost>
```

When inspecting PHP configuration, I see:

```
 Directive               Local value   Master value
 upload_max_filesize     2M            2M
```

What is the right way to do this when using PHP 8?

Comment: _"What is the right way to do this"_ - that depends first and foremost on _how_ PHP is integrated into your web server in the first place. Apache module, fcgi, ...

Comment: This is the right way, but please show the detail of error.

Comment: If you have done this in apache virtulahost it was with mod_php. Probably, as now you use php8, you have php-fpm which is recommended. In this case, you must use a separate fpm pool for the specific virtualhost in this way you can specify a personalized php.ini. Alternatively, you can specify the settings in the code via ini_set();

Comment: Question  has been updated with details about how PHP is installed and integrated with web server.

Answer (score 0):

You have php running via fpm. fpm is a separate process with which apache interacts, in your case, via socket file.

As in my comment, you have 2 options to personalize the php settings:

1. using ini_set()
2. separate fpm pool for the specific virtualhost

via ini_set() is the fastest and simplest way, just add the following to the page where you manage the upload

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
```

The second option is a bit more complicated, you need to configure a new fpm pool. By doing it quickly, just copy the existing configuration, usually in /etc/php/8.1/pool.d) and modify it. They key line are:

```
listen = /var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock
```

to

```
listen = /var/run/php/php8.1-mysite-fpm.sock
```

and add/modify

```
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 10M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 10M
```

Restart php-fpm and verify that it goes up without error

Then make your apache virtualhost point to the new socket

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>:
    SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-mysite-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

restart apache and it should work

Comment: Thabks! However, `upload_max_filesize` is mode `PHP_INI_PERDIR`. which means entry can be set in `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` or `.user.ini`. I.e. not on the page managing the upload. I've confirmed that this doesn't work. Exploring setting up a separate fpm pool, but unclear what to name copy of directory `pool.d` and where to put it.

Comment: pool.d is the directory, fpm read all the file in it and accordingly create the pool.
Sorry as I was unclear, by copy I meant copy the default configuration file, usually www.conf, to a new one in same directory and modify it